# Request never executes in node.js

Tags: node.js, request

I'm struggling with this senseless problem: I made a request in node.js but it never executes. I tried writing it in every way, I also tried other API tools like Postman which actually work and give me also code to use but nothing work. Console doesn't log anything, no errors, no responses, nothing.

This is (one of the thousands versions I made of):

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks',
    headers: {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        authorization: 'Basic secret-code-auth-string'
    },
    body: '{"merchant":"bnO7G*Q58OJqLJTG25wNTGYN","executor":"bnO7G*Q58OJqLJTG25wNTGYN","destination":"vrxou2HY~7IpqH*KcWtizITO","recipients":["XbFxqmYVIOxt3ufCtq4tSBh3"],"pickupTask":"false","notes":"Mega informazioni per chi consegna, lista prodotti e indirizzo di consegna","autoAssign":{"mode":"load","team":"hVNbKGAbb*hj9uVXI6ndoZ6F"}}'
};

console.log(options);

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

Everything is so simple - I use request like 20 times in the rest of this code that I'm going crazy!
Thank you

Comment: Can you please re-check the headers you used in postman for your endpoint as 'content-type': 'application/json'? (if applicable)

Comment: On the first line of your `request()` callback, add: `console.log(err); console.log(response);` so you can see exactly what comes back before any other code executes.  FYI, doing a `throw new Error()` where you have it does absolutely no good because that callback is async so the exception just goes into the bowels of the http engine and is nothing you can catch or see.

Comment: When I run your code in node.js, I get this body `{"code":"InvalidCredentials","message":{"error":1102,"message":"The API key provided is invalid.","request":"476eb064-70d5-46b1-9945-fe67cb149e82","cause":"This key does not exist or is no longer active."}}`  which is obviously because you removed the actual key from your posting.  So, the basics of the request seem to work just fine in node.js for me.  The exact code I ran is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/12r9y3b5/ (it's not runnable from the jsFiddle - I ran it from my command line).

Comment: As usual it was a huge mistake: somehow my code was overriding the request variable - same name for require('request') and something alse that I didn't find out.
_So sorry_...